# Joining with a tags table -- should I join in PHP or on the DB server?

Tags: database, join, performance

Using the [Toxi solution](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html), *how should I* select the tags for a certain "Bookmark" (to keep the Delicious theme):

I can either:

1) Join in a single query:

```
select bookmark.title, bookmark.url, 
(
  SELECT group_concat( tags.name ) as tagNames
  FROM taggings INNER JOIN tags
  ON taggings.tagId_fk=tags.tagId
  WHERE taggings.bookmarkId_fk = bookmarks.bookmarkId_fk
)
from bookmarks
where bookmarks.id=1 ;

^^ That gives
title    url               tagNames
A bkmrk  http://url.com    tag1,tag2,tag3
```

2)  **Use two queries**:  one to retrieve the bookmark id's to display, then another to retrieve the tags for those bookmarks.  The results can then be merged in PHP.

So really this question is:  In general **efficiency/database load-wise** is it better to do more joining in a single query or multiple queries?

How do you make that kind of decision?  Or do you simply not think about it until load causes a problem?

Comment: Good question - I often wonder this.  It's easier to scale web-servers horizontally than databases, which makes me wonder if I should push more of the 'merging' logic onto the web-server, or to stick with SQL joins, which feel more natural (SQL being all about working with sets, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Server side is more efficient.

In both cases, the server must read all of the tags.

If you bring them to PHP, then they must all travel over the wire and PHP has to fiddle with them.

If you do them on the server, the finished answer (smaller) comes over the wire ready for PHP to pass it up to the UI.

Comment: Reasonable.. I was thinking more along the lines of overloading the database.  Is it "easier" for the database to shove more raw data at the PHP server, or sift through it itself?  At what point do you go "this is too much work for the DBMS to be doing, lets move it over to PHP?"

Comment: "at what point...." far far later than most people think, and even then pushing it to the app doesn't help much, because the CPU still has to handle the job of going out to disk and getting all of that data, plus pushing it out over the wire.